# how to show same size images in equal to width of screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show images in equal to width of screen.here my code:-

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/m"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/m"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

My layout look like:-

[image]

Anyone can help me how i solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout_height` attribute:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/m"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/m"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to do that from java code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.weight = 0.5f;
ImageView = new ImageView(this);
myImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: If I created Imageview programmatically then how can i do this.

Comment: Why the `layout_weight="0.5"`?? I mean why dont you use just `layout_weight="1"` in each one? The `android:weightSum="1"` isn't necessary BTW. And the attribute `"fill_parent"` is deprecated, use `"match_parent"` instead.

Comment: @astinx 0.5 or 1 or whatever you want, the important is to use the same value for both images. You are right for *fill_parent*, i haven't paid attention on that, i'll update my answer.